# Is this ajax request actually doing anything?

Tags: jquery, ajax, lazy-loading

Ok, this sounds like a weird question, but I"m using jquery to make an ajax request so i can preload a bunch of images, then I want to show all the images once everything is loaded. While the request is being made there is an animated loader gif that sits on the page.

I have the following code, and it makes the ajax request and loads the images like it's supposed to. I never see the animated gif, and I'm not sure if it's just loading so fast, or if something isn't working right. Also, once the ajax is successful, it still looks like the images need to load, they don't just pop up, it looks like they're still loading.

This is what I'm using:

```
var load_gallery = function(){
    var images = $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: "/index.php/main/get_images",
        success: function(html){
            $("#gallery-images").html(html);
            $("#image-loader-animation").addClass('hide');
            $('#cat-selector-all').addClass('link-selected');               
        }
    });
}
```

Is the above suppose to wait until everything in that ajax request loads and then display on the page? If not, is there a way I can make that ajax request and wait until everything is completely loaded before displaying it all and hiding the loader gif.

Basically a lazy loader.

Thanks

EDIT: I updated it to use .load, it still seems to be having the same problem... not sure if this is correct:

```
var load_gallery = function(){
    $("#gallery-images").load('/index.php/main/get_images', function () {
        $("#gallery-images").show();
        $("#image-loader-animation").addClass('hide');
        $('#cat-selector-all').addClass('link-selected');
    });

}
```

EDIT: This is the request... could it be because I"m using the placeholders as images for now?

```
    <div class="site gallery-webdev">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/700" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    asdf
    </div>
</div>
<div class="site gallery-webdev">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/700" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    asdf
    </div>
</div>
<div class="site gallery-seo">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/1000/700/0" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    asdf
    </div>
</div>
<div class="site gallery-fd">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placedog.com/1000/700" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    asdf
    </div>
</div>
<div class="site">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/700" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    asdf
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the page that you're sending the AJAX request to is PHP, you can make sure the animated gif is showing up by using PHP's [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) command to just delay the response.

Answer (score 0):

The success function will only be called if your AJAX request was successfull.

If you're working on your local machine, requests are fast. Try the script on your server as well.

To solve your problem: can you show us your request? I would think that you only load the  part, not the images itselfs.

Comment: Hey Phil, take a look at this plugin: http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/preloadImages/scripts/preloadCssImages.jQuery_v5.js

Answer (score 0):

You ajax is only getting html and putting it in the div you want. This is not loading the images because until you put them on the page or create a javascript Image object the server will not request them. Try using this [plugin](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/) instead. I takes the Image.onload and creates events for the loaded image. I used it on a project no too long ago for lazy loading and it works pretty well.

As for the spinner, make you you create it before the ajax/image request and them remove it once everything is compete (whether it is successful or has an error)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it without a plugin, but I will see if I can take stuff from that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the .load event to the div to get a callback for when all it's content is loaded. This should work for you:

```
$("#gallery-images").load(function () {
    $("#gallery-images").show();
});
```

Note that I'm assuming what you want isn't the AJAX request to finish (that's what happens when you get into the success callback function), rather you want the other content to load and then let you know when it's loaded (which isn't AJAX).

Comment: Yea, that's more of what I'm looking for... hmm ok I'll try this, thanks

Comment: Hmm, so I"m a little confused I think... do I add this to the ajax request? or remove that ajax request entirely?

Comment: The idea with this is once you've done the AJAX req and you've set the content use this to let you know when the div has finished loading everything within it (eg. all images etc are loaded), I'd stick it straight after: `$("#gallery-images").html(html);`

Comment: In your example above you seem to be confusing the 2 .load methods jquery provides. They are documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) it may be worth using `$('#gallery-images').bind('load', function () { /* do something */ });` so you can clearly distinguish between the 2 different load methods.